# Nextjs Middleware doesn't work with Next Auth V5 on Amplify: "There was a problem with the server configuration" and "Host must be trusted"

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify, next-auth

Environment
Environment
System:
OS: macOS 14.3.1
CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
Memory: 174.97 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 18.17.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 10.2.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/npm
Browsers:
Brave Browser: 121.1.62.156
Chrome: 121.0.6167.184
Safari: 17.3.1

I'm utilizing Amplify with NextAuth V5. Currently, I'm facing an issue where I haven't specified the NEXTAUTH_URL. This seems to be problematic on Amplify as it still refers back to localhost. However, the main issue is that the middleware isn't providing the correct output for auth.req.

auth.req gives me "message": "There was a problem with the server configuration. Check the server logs for more information."

Interestingly, the code I deployed works flawlessly on Vercel without specifying the NEXTAUTH_URL, and the middleware operates perfectly. I suspect there might be an issue with how the middleware is being interpreted on Amplify.

Details: I'm using NEXTAUTH_SECRET, but not NEXTAUTH_URL in my .env. The NEXTAUTH_SECRET can be read in middleware so the issue is not being able to find the .env variable on amplify.

I'm using Prisma with Mongodb Adapter as well.

Expected behavior
The auth.req should return a user if its logged in or null if its not, not a message error.

The localhost should not be used, rather the subdomain that I'm using (i.e. app.DOMAIN.com or dev.DOMAIN.com)

src/middleware.ts

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

import authConfig from '@/auth.config';
import {
  DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
  apiAuthPrefix,
  authRoutes,
  publicRoutes,
} from './routes';

const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);

/* @ts-ignore */
export default auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;

  if (nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/ingest')) {
    console.log('hit hit');
    return null;
  }

  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;

  console.log('isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn);

  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

  console.log('isApiAuthRoute', isApiAuthRoute);
  console.log('isPublicRoute', isPublicRoute);
  console.log('isAuthRoute', isAuthRoute);

  if (isApiAuthRoute) {
    return null;
  }

  if (isAuthRoute) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl));
    }
    return null;
  }
  if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute) {
    let callbackUrl = nextUrl.pathname;
    if (nextUrl.search) {
      callbackUrl += nextUrl.search;
    }

    const encodedCallbackUrl = encodeURIComponent(callbackUrl);

    return Response.redirect(
      new URL(`/?callbackUrl=${encodedCallbackUrl}`, nextUrl),
    );
  }

  return null;

  // req.auth
});

// Optionally, don't invoke Middleware on some paths
export const config = {
  // matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'],
};
src/auth.ts

import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { UserRole } from '@prisma/client';
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter';

import { db } from '@/lib/db';
import authConfig from '@/auth.config';
import { getUserById } from '@/data/user';
import { getTwoFactorConfirmationByUserId } from '@/data/two-factor-confirmation';
import { getAccountByUserId } from './data/account';

export const {
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
  unstable_update,
  handlers: { GET, POST },
} = NextAuth({
  trustHost: true,
  logger: {
    debug: console.log,
    error: console.error,
    warn: console.warn,
  },
  debug: true,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/',
    error: '/auth/error',
  },

  events: {
    async linkAccount({ user }) {
      await db.user.update({
        where: { id: user.id },
        data: { emailVerified: new Date() },
      });
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account }) {
      // Allow OAuth without email verification
      if (account?.provider !== 'credentials') return true;

      const existingUser = await getUserById(user.id as string);

      // Prevent sign in without email verification
      if (!existingUser?.emailVerified) return false;

      if (existingUser.isTwoFactorEnabled) {
        const twoFactorConfirmation = await getTwoFactorConfirmationByUserId(
          existingUser.id,
        );

        if (!twoFactorConfirmation) return false;

        // Delete two factor confirmation for next sign in
        await db.twoFactorConfirmation.delete({
          where: { id: twoFactorConfirmation.id },
        });
      }

      return true;
    },
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token.sub && session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }

      if (token.role && session.user) {
        session.user.role = token.role as UserRole;
      }

      if (session.user) {
        session.user.isTwoFactorEnabled = token.isTwoFactorEnabled as boolean;
      }

      if (session.user) {
        session.user.family_name = token.family_name as string;
        session.user.given_name = token.given_name as string;
        session.user.email = token.email as string;
        session.user.isOAuth = token.isOAuth as boolean;
        session.user.completedOnboarding = token.completedOnboarding as boolean;
        session.user.betaAccess = token.betaAccess as boolean;
        session.user.dailyMessageCooldownCounter =
          token.dailyMessageCooldownCounter as Date;
        session.user.dailyMessageCount = token.dailyMessageCount as number;
        session.user.stripe_customer_id = token.stripe_customer_id as string;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token }) {
      if (!token.sub) return token;

      const existingUser = await getUserById(token.sub);

      if (!existingUser) return token;

      const existingAccount = await getAccountByUserId(existingUser.id);

      token.isOAuth = !!existingAccount;
      token.family_name = existingUser.family_name;
      token.given_name = existingUser.given_name;
      token.email = existingUser.email;
      token.role = existingUser.role;
      token.isTwoFactorEnabled = existingUser.isTwoFactorEnabled;
      token.completedOnboarding = existingUser.completedOnboarding;
      token.betaAccess = existingUser.betaAccess;
      token.dailyMessageCooldownCounter =
        existingUser.dailyMessageCooldownCounter;
      token.dailyMessageCount = existingUser.dailyMessageCount;
      token.stripe_customer_id = existingUser.stripe_customer_id;

      return token;
    },
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: { strategy: 'jwt' },
  ...authConfig,
});
```

[Localhost error is still showing on Amplify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZWFK.png)

[Amplify can't read auth.req in middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMU8I.png)

The two errors I'm getting:

```
�[31m[auth][error]�[0m UntrustedHost: Host must be trusted. URL was: https://dev.xyz.com/api/auth/session .Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#untrustedhost
```

```
req {
"sourcePage": "/src/middleware",
"message": "There was a problem with the server configuration. Check the server logs for more information."
}
```

Again, everything works when deployed to Vercel but doesn't when deployed to Amplify. Any help would be appreciated!

I tried everything that I could think of. Whenever I put NEXTAUTH_URL it doesn't solve the /src/middlware issue on amplify.

I then deployed to vercel without the NEXTAUTH_URL and it works perfectly fine. I think the issue has to be with some configuration on Amplify.

Comment: I am also encountering the same issue. I was following Antonio's YouTube video tutorial and implemented the authentication with some variations, but I encountered the same error as yours in Amplify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update or add these in your environment variables as following:

In `.env.production` or `env.local` files

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://YOUR_LOCAL_OR_DEPLOYED_HOST_URL:HOST_PORT
AUTH_TRUST_HOST=http://YOUR_LOCAL_OR_DEPLOYED_HOST_URL:HOST_PORT
```

Results be like:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://192.152.1.1:3000
AUTH_TRUST_HOST=ttp://192.152.1.1:3000
```